# Check an array of objects has the property

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How can I check the proper property contains in an array of objects in JS?

```
const array=[
    { name: "A", hasCar: true},
    { name: "B" }
];

// if (array has "hasCar") {
//    do something
// }
```

I want to if array has `"hasCar"` or not. 
`array.includes` doesnt work on array of object.

Should I use `.hasOwnProperty("hasCar")` or any solutions?

Comment: `if (array.some(o => o.hasOwnProperty("hasCar"))`

Answer (score 0):

You could take [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and check with [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```js
const array = [{ name: "A", hasCar: true}, { name: "B" }];

console.log(array.some(o => o.hasOwnProperty('hasCar')));
```